# trino-python-client oauth in jupyterlab

Tags: python, redirect, oauth, trino

I have installed [trino-python-client](https://github.com/trinodb/trino-python-client) in custom jupyterlab image and it works if I use basic authentication.

I want to use the OAuth services I have set up in trino to make things simpler for users.
This also works fine in ipython3 see below. But doesn't work in jupyterlab.
Jupyterlab is hiding the redirect URL, never prints out the redirection URL.

In ipython3 is see this

```
In [1]: import trino
...: conn = trino.dbapi.connect(
...:     host='trino.somedomain.net',
...:     port=443,
...:     user='first.last',
...:     catalog='iceberg',
...:     schema='ds_scratch',
...:     http_scheme='https',
...:     auth=trino.auth.OAuth2Authentication(),
...: )
...: cur = conn.cursor()

In [2]: cur.execute('SELECT * FROM system.runtime.nodes')

Open the following URL in the browser for the external authentication:
https://trino.somedomain.net/oauth2/token/initiate/042f6e4167d4e6a3f70068ec4389037c2b9c34f3ec356ddc5522a3e13e179fd9


In [3]: rows = cur.fetchall()
In [4]: print(rows)
[['trino-coordinator-69dffc6f9f-pvpg4',...]]
```

I can see the redirection URL and complete the OAuth flow and everything works.
But in jupyterlab it never prints the URL. How do I change this?

In jpyterlab I see the following.

```
In [1]: import trino
In [2]: conn = trino.dbapi.connect(
host='trino.somedomain.net',
port=443,
user='first.last',
catalog='iceberg',
schema='ds_scratch',
http_scheme='https',
auth=trino.auth.OAuth2Authentication(),
)
In [3]: cur = conn.cursor()
In [4]: cur.execute('show tables from iceberg.ds_scratch')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_170/588296735.py in <module>
----> 1 cur.execute('show tables from iceberg.ds_scratch')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trino/dbapi.py in execute(self, operation, params)
    434         else:
    435             self._query = trino.client.TrinoQuery(self._request, sql=operation)
--> 436             result = self._query.execute()
    437         self._iterator = iter(result)
    438         return result

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trino/client.py in execute(self, additional_http_headers)
    523             raise exceptions.TrinoUserError("Query has been cancelled", self.query_id)
    524
--> 525         response = self._request.post(self._sql, additional_http_headers)
    526         status = self._request.process(response)
    527         self._info_uri = status.info_uri

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trino/client.py in post(self, sql, additional_http_headers)
    337         http_headers.update(additional_http_headers or {})
    338
--> 339         http_response = self._post(
    340             self.statement_url,
    341             data=data,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trino/exceptions.py in decorated(*args, **kwargs)
    121             for attempt in range(1, max_attempts + 1):
    122                 try:
--> 123                     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    124                     if any(guard(result) for guard in conditions):
    125                         handle_retry.retry(func, args, kwargs, None, attempt)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in post(self, url, data, json, **kwargs)
    588         """
    589
--> 590         return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    591
    592     def put(self, url, data=None, **kwargs):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    540         }
    541         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 542         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    543
    544         return resp

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    653
    654         # Send the request
--> 655         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    656
    657         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    437         try:
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,
    441                     url=url,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    668
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,
    672                 method,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    379         # Trigger any extra validation we need to do.
    380         try:
--> 381             self._validate_conn(conn)
    382         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:
    383             # Py2 raises this as a BaseSSLError, Py3 raises it as socket timeout.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    976         # Force connect early to allow us to validate the connection.
    977         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 978             conn.connect()
    979
    980         if not conn.is_verified:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    307     def connect(self):
    308         # Add certificate verification
--> 309         conn = self._new_conn()
    310         hostname = self.host
    311

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    157
    158         try:
--> 159             conn = connection.create_connection(
    160                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
    161             )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
    72             if source_address:
    73                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 74             sock.connect(sa)
    75             return sock
    76

KeyboardInterrupt:

In [5]: rows = cur.fetchall()
```